QGIS equivalent to ArcGIS Pro's Thematic Map Series
I am currently working on a series of bird range maps that requires exporting PNG's of groups layers at the same boundary/Map frame.
ArcGIS Pro has the Thematic Map series tool that allows the export of all individual layers within a Group to be exported at the same map frame/extent, you can select which pages of the thematic map series you want to export if you make changes, and it quickly batch exports all layers in that group as individual maps.
I know QGIS has Atlas, and map themes, but neither seem to be able to iterate through layers in a group and then export them as individual PNG's.
Does anyone have tips to if this can be done with Atlas and/or map themes?

I have the same problem right now. Havent actively tried any solution yet, but it should be possible to iterate through the layers in quesiton via a Python script and export after every iteration.
Let's say you put all your layers in a group like the radio-group in ArcGIS, but turn their layer visibility off. In the Python script you search for the ID of the group object and get all IDs of the items in the group. Then you iterate over them, turn the current layer visible, refresh the layout, export and turn the visibility off again. Upp to the next ID.
This should work. Depending on the number of layers you need to take care of it won't be as efficient as just doing it by hand. (my problem right now)
If I decide to go for this solution I will post my script here, though.

This does not answer the question.
If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question.
To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question.
Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question.
